# i/o error while running the build in jenkins

Tags: c, unix, gcc, jenkins, solaris-10

I am getting some kind of i/o error while compiling code in Jenkins. I am not sure exactly if this it is related to slave which is solaris 10 or network or code itself. I think it is not the code issue because everytime it produces error on different file. Can anyone please help me? Following is one of the error generated:

```
Compiling /enert/gap/att/loop/src/IM_library.c
Compiling /enert/gap/att/loop/src/test_functions.cc
/enert/gap/att/loop/src/freak.c:135:16: /enert/gap/att/ena/PT.h: I/O error
```

Any help will be appreciated !!

Comment: The first question is: do you get the same error when you compile from command line outside of Jenkins? Do you get the same error when you compile on Jenkins slave using the command line (but outside of Jenkins UI)

Comment: I can successfully compile outside the jenkins from the shell in the same host that jenkins using. SO the issue is on Jenkins only.

Comment: Make sure you try with the same user/permission as Jenkins will be running.  Oft times things will work when you use your account, but won't when you use the 'jenkins' account as it has different permissions and other settings.